# tile background image css

Tags: html, css

I want to repeat background image in a div but without specifying height, i want it to be flexible, if any amount of data comes in background should still be there. if i don't specify height it does not shows there but other properties like margin auto is applied.

any suggestions.

Comment: can we possibly see some code? Just so we can get an idea of whats going on. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use the property `background-repeat repeat` for that div tag. It should keep itself inside the div tag.

css:

```
.background-element {
  // just add
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="background-element">
  <!-- content -->
</div>
```

Comment: "It should keep itself inside the div tag." clarify plz

Comment: When the div tag is rendered by the browser, the area that div tag creates, is where the background image should repeat.

Answer (score 0):

```
.background-element {
    background: url(tile.gif) repeat;
}
```

This will repeat even if the element's width/height is unknown.

Comment: nah, in my case it's not working i have a .png in background.

Comment: the way i am using is overflow:auto; but when i resize my window scroll bars come in and make it ugly.

Comment: you can imagine how scroll bars inside divs will look like.

Comment: Hmm.. do you need the scrollbars? Ditch the overflow:auto to get rid of them. I'm really unsure what's breaking the background, perhaps a screenshot would help?